# HQL query take attribute from wrong class

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to execute the following query :

```
returnValue = (Long) super.createQuery("Select Count(*) From User u Left Outer Join u.rolesRelated r "
                    + "Where r.role.id = :roleId And u.id = :userId")
                    .setParameter("userId", userId)
                    .setParameter("roleId", roleId)
                    .getSingleResult();
```

But I'm getting this error :

```
 org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: role.id of: com.sp.common.core.model.User
```

This property does not exists since role.id is in user.rolesRelated, not in user. This is my hibernate mapping:

```
<class name="com.sp.common.core.model.User" table="user">
/* more meaningless properties */
        <set cascade="all" name="rolesRelated" sort="unsorted" table="sec_rperfil_usuario"
            lazy="false" fetch="join">
            <key column="id_usuario" />
            <composite-element class="com.sp.common.core.model.UserRole">
                <many-to-one name="role" class="com.sp.common.core.model.Role"
                    column="id_perfil" cascade="none" lazy="false" fetch="join" />
            </composite-element>
        </set>
</class>
```

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing another explicit join on Role.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User u LEFT OUTER JOIN u.rolesRelated rr 
LEFT OUTER JOIN rr.role r WHERE r.id = :roleId And u.id = :userId
```